# 3D fitting with SVD - Uncertainty estimate

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, svd

I am trying to use SVD to fit a particle track through a detector and getting the direction vector from the right singular matrix.
The matrix $A$ is defined by the positions $\vec{p}_i$ of the signals minus the average $\vec{p}_0$.
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ x_i & y_i & z_i \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} \overline{x_i} & \overline{y_i} & \overline{z_i} \end{pmatrix}$$
$$ A = U \Sigma V^T $$
The first row of $V^T$ should then be the direction vector $\vec{v}$ of the track. So the particle track should be described by the parametric equation $$\vec{p}_0 + t \cdot \vec{v} $$

So my question is - obviously the positions of the signals do have an uncertainty (pixel size in $x$ and $y$ and time resolution in $z$).
What can I do to have an uncertainty estimate for the direction vector?
My goal is to extend the track to $z=0$ and get the $(x,y)$ position on that plane where I would like to know the uncertainty of the position.

Comment: Shouldn't that be related to the other singular values? In that they give the variance orthogonal to the first singular vector?

Comment: Are you saying that we that the particle actually follows a linear path, or are you saying that the first row of $V^T$ corresponds to a linear approximation of the track?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Both, $V^T$ is a linear approximation, but also the majority of the particles actually follow a linear path.

Comment: @LutzLehmann But I never added information about the real measurement uncertainties, so they should also somehow be included I guess?